# Modifying png alpha channel with Go breaks the image color

Tags: image, go, png, rgba

I'm trying to change png RGBA values with Go's image/png package. I have no problems modifying R, G or B but when I alter alpha values the image "breaks", other values change with no apparent pattern.

Nothing of this happens if I leave alpha channel untouched.

I decode the png this way:

```
img, err := png.Decode(file)
if (err != nil) {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer file.Close()

rgba := image.NewRGBA(img.Bounds())
draw.Draw(rgba, rgba.Bounds(), img, image.Point{0,0}, draw.Src)
```

And then this way I modify and encode the image:

```
rgba.Pix[0] = uint8(254)  // red channel of 1st pixel
rgba.Pix[1] = uint8(254)  // green channel of 1st pixel
rgba.Pix[2] = uint8(254)  // blue channel of 1st pixel
rgba.Pix[3] = uint8(254)  // alpha channel of 1st pixel

new_file, err := os.Create("new.png")
if (err != nil) {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer new_file.Close()

png.Encode(new_file, rgba)
```

this is 2x2 solid white image's pixel slice

```
[255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255]
```

and this is the same slice after the change

```
[255 255 255 254 255 255 255 254 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255]
```

and I only modified the first pixel. I'm clueless about what might be happening.

Thanks in advance :)

---

EDIT 1

Making this change over the same white 2x2 image

```
[255 254 254 254 254 255 255 254 254 254 254 254 254 254 255 255]
```

with both rgba.SetRGBA and rgba.Pix way, I end up with this

```
[0 254 254 254 254 0 0 254 254 254 254 254 254 254 255 255]
```

Comment: When I test I get `[254 254 254 254 255 255 255 255 ...]`. On what kind of computer are you running your code?

Comment: @md2perpe arch linux x86_64 on a lenovo laptop with an intel i5-3210M (don't know if that's the info you were asking for). Did you try to decode the image to check if the values are correct ? Because if I do fmt.Println(rgba) after encoding everything seems ok, but when I open the image it has wrong colors. Decoding the image once again shows the wrong values on the rgba.

Comment: Then you are running on the same kind of processor as I am (x86_64), so there should not be a difference due to different endians.

Comment: How are you printing the slice?

Comment: @md2perpe I'm printing the whole image.RGBA. It prints the slice, the max and min coordinates (and a number that idk what it means).

Comment: That number is the *stride*. As I understand it, it's the length in bytes of one row in the image. https://golang.org/src/image/image.go#L59